# Optimize performance MySql SELECT query with EXISTS function

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) number_products 
FROM catalog_parameter_product_value pv
JOIN catalog_product p ON p.id=pv.id_product
JOIN catalog_category_product_mm pmm ON p.id=pmm.id_product
JOIN catalog_category c ON c.id=pmm.id_category
JOIN catalog_category_parameter_mm parmm ON c.id=parmm.id_category
WHERE
EXISTS (
    SELECT pv.id FROM catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm codmm
    JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value pvin ON pvin.id=codmm.id_parameter_product_value
    WHERE pvin.id_product = pv.id_product  AND  (codmm.id_parameter_codebook = 1)
)
AND p.state='2' AND p.hidden=0
```

Duration of the query is 19 sec.

When I remove EXISTS, duration of query is only 0.4 sec.

Anyway, I need exists function to filter products based on the selected attribute.

Number of rows tables:

- catalog_parameter_product_value: 10000
- catalog_product: 1000
- catalog_category_product_mm: 10000
- catalog_category: 10
- catalog_category_parameter_mm: 10
- catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm: 10000

EXPLAIN:
[image]

Can I optimize a query and get duration to a few millisecond?

Comment: Without the EXISTS the response time is 400 ms, but you want to include the EXISTS and get response time in a few milliseconds... Suggestion: do JOIN instead.

Comment: Try changing `SELECT pv.id FROM` to `SELECT 1 FROM` in subquery

Comment: The subquery by itself how long does it take?Table definition for table p would be useful.

Comment: Changed to "SELECT 1 FROM" but still is duration 19 sec

Comment: It's a correlated sub-query, it can't be run alone.

Comment: @kevas ok try adding `LIMIT 1` in subquery

Comment: @jarlh, using a join instead of `exists` changes the logic.

Comment: Yes  It's a correlated sub-query, it can't be run alone...

Comment: @madforstrength adding LIMIT 1 and still duration 19 sec

Comment: If you remove AND  (codmm.id_parameter_codebook = 1)?

Comment: @Mihai when i remove AND (codmm.id_parameter_codebook = 1) duration is 4 sec

Comment: @kevas remove quotations from `p.state='2'`

Comment: @madforstrength removed quotations. duration 19 sec

Comment: You could remove the EXISTS creating a new join between catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm and catalog_parameter_product_value, and using this condition: pv.id=codmm.id_parameter_product_value AND codmm.id_parameter_codebook = 1

Comment: What is the distribution of id_parameter_codebook?That is when you do SELECT DISTINCT id_parameter_codebook FROM t how many rows do you get compared to the total number of rows?Also what type is the column id_parameter_codebook ?

Comment: @DanBracuk, it doesn't. Still same "DISTINCT p.id".

Comment: @Miguel when i remove exists and creating new join, is now duration a few millisecond but conditions "AND codmm.id_parameter_codebook = 1" may be more and then query does not return the desired output.